# Question regarding SSL / TLS / Certificates in general

Tags: tls, certificates, webserver

for the last two days I played around a bit with nginx's SSL configuration.
A question came up:

I created asymmetric key using
`$ openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout nginx.key -out nginx.crt`
nginx config:
`ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL';`

Chrome now says: `[..] Connection encrypted with AES_256_CBC [..]`
So what does the rsa:4096 in the openssl req command refer to?

I've already read some tutorials about SSL/TLS, but none of them answered my question.

My chain of thought:
rsa:4096 specifies the strength of the initial handshake, where client and server exchange the symmetric key (in the case above: AES 256bit encryption, cbc mode) to encrypt data.
Is this correct?
If so, then this means that the *raw-encrypted data* itself can't be decrypted by someone who only has the certificate's private key, right? He needs the symmetric key for that.

I have to admit (if you haven't already noticed :D) that I'm a SSL newb.
Can you recommend a good-read which explains everything (certificates etc.)?

Comment: RSA 4096 (bits) is the strength of asymmetric key you're using for the public key exchange.  I would suggest reading [How does SSl/TLS work?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work)

Comment: Adding some clarification for you.  Yes, check the main How does SSL/TLS work, but the AES identifies the actual symmetric key used, but that is established by a key exchange which occurs using the certificate.  The certificate is what you were making in openssl.